# Why is the javascript loose equality not the same as the truthy test?

Tags: javascript

In javascript, a (admittedly sloppy) way of checking whether a variable is set is to check whether it's "truthy", by

```
var blah;

blah = "foo"; // in real code, this assignment might happen only sometimes

if(blah) {
  console.log('blah is set'); 
}
```

I had thought "loose" equality operator was equivalent to a truthy test. Howcome, then, the expression `"foo" == true` evaluates to `false`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if( expression )` checks for truthiness while `x == y` uses *conversions* to determine equality. It's not exactly the same concept.

The conversions are detailed on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators). For `==`:

> If the two operands are not of the same type, JavaScript converts the
>   operands, then applies strict comparison. If either operand is a
>   number or a boolean, the operands are converted to numbers if
>   possible; else if either operand is a string, the string operand is
>   converted to a number if possible. If both operands are objects, then
>   JavaScript compares internal references which are equal when operands
>   refer to the same object in memory.

Based on this, `"foo" == true` is equivalent to `NaN === 1` and is false.